# ElasticSearch: Exact match for multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch-6

How can I generate a query like this?

```
select * from topic where field1 = "abc" and field2 = "xyz"
```

I've tried the following but I can't get the correct syntax:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/topic/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "terms" : { 
       "field1": "abc",
       "field2": "xyz"
    }
  }
}
'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about...

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "field1": "abc"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "field2": "xyz"
          }
        }
        ]
      }
  }
}
```

The [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) doesn't do what you want. Instead it searches for different values within the same key.